# Is there a way to check if a string coming from a JPA query is a valid custom enum?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, enums

I have an entity model with an inner custom enum field, like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_CUSTOM")
public class CustModel{

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
@Column(name = "CUSTOM", length = 3, nullable = false)
private EnumCustom enumCustom;

}

public enum EnumCustom{
A, B, C, D, UNK;
}
```

//UNK stands for UNKNOWN

In that table TABLE_CUSTOM there is a column that contains the possible values for enumCustom fields, but there are cases that some not valid values (like E, F) might come, in that case i would like to set that field as UNK(unknown).
Is there a way by using an annotation on that field or something similar for fixing this problem?

Comment: You could use an [attribute converter](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-attribute-converters).

Comment: Actually, my application is deployed on WebSphere 9, which seems not to read properly @Converter annotation, this behaviour doesn't happen on JBoss on which the annotation works.

Answer (score 0):

You could use @PostLoad to populate a second field with the correct enum value:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TABLE_CUSTOM")
public class CustModel{

    // populated with database String value via ORM framework
    private String enumDatabase;
    private EnumCustom enumCustom;

    @PostLoad
    private EnumCustom enumCustom;
        enumCustom = EnumCustom.valueOf(enumDatabase);
    }
}


public enum EnumCustom{
    A, B, C, D, UNK;

    public static void fromValue(String enumDatabase) {
        for(EnumCustom enumCustom : values()) {
            if (enumCustom.name().equals(enumDatabase) {
                return enumCustom;
            }
        }
        return EnumCustom.UNK;
    }
}
```